# Why do function in Flink need to be serializeable?

Tags: apache-flink

Consider the `FlatMapFunction` in Flink. It's required that any implementation of this must be serializable.

I am trying to understand why this is the case, can anyone explain? Are all of these operator instances created at the job manager than serialized and sent to task managers?

Answer (score 1):

> Are all of these operator instances created at the job manager than serialized and sent to task managers?

You have already answered your question :)
That's exactly what happens.

It worths to mention that it isn't only for distributed jobs, it's used for fault tolerance too.

The system recovers data from checkpoints then re-deploys the entire distributed dataflow, and gives each operator the state that was snapshotted as part of checkpoint.